# git cherry-pick : explanation. Why does it give conflicts and differences?

Tags: git

I have two branches on my git project: release and dev. I made a picture to show the structure and what I want.

[image: Hand-drawn graph of what I have and what I want]

To copy commit number 5 from dev branch to release branch, I made a cherry-pick on release branch.

1. Why are there conflicts when I cherry-picked on release branch?

   Cherry-pick applies differences between commits and common ancestor, so, in this case the common ancestor is commit number 3. Cherry-pick should apply the same differences on commit 3 on release branch. There is nothing after commit 3 on release branch, so I don't understand the conflicts.
2. In the order to resolve conflicts, I used:

   `git cherry-pick -X theirs commit5`

   on the release branch.

So my 2nd question is: why are there differences between commit 5 on release branch and commit 5 on dev branch?

The `diff` command show a lot of differences. With the option `-X theirs` all the changes of dev branch's commit 5 should be applied, no?

Comment: What `cherry-pick` picks is the difference between the given commit, and the *given commit*'s parent.  Given your drawing, if you attempt to `git cherry-pick <hash-of-5>` Git computes `git diff <hash-of-4> <hash-of-5>` and applies that to your current commit, whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

`git cherry-pick`, as far as I know, just takes the diffs from the commit and tries to apply it to your files. That's why there can be some conflicts.

As for the second part of your question, I didn't really get what you meant. The two commits (let's call them 5 and 5') have a different base, thus should be different (their sha is different, the lines they change is different, etc.).
All the changes that can be applied; will be applied. If commit 5 introduces some changes to files that weren't present in commit 3, those obviously won't be propagated in commit 5'. This is also why it it a good idea to keep commits as atomic as possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree git cherry-pick takes the diffs from the commit and tries to apply it. I think the differences must have a point of reference and, for me, cherry-pick take the diffs with the common ancestor commit (here the commit 3). Any files haven't been modified since commit 3 on release branch, so i still don't understand why conflicts appear. /n Thanks for your 2d answer, i thought cherry-pick add new files. Here i have a java file already exists on commit 3 and it is different between commit 5 and 5' after cherry-pick. I don't understand why...

Comment: Well, for starters, you probably have the changes from commit 4 in this file, after commit 5. Those changes won't appear in commit 5'. Or maybe you want your project to look *exactly* the same between commit 5' and 5, but with only one commit? In that case, merge+squash is what you want, or cherry pick multiple individual commits (+squash).

Comment: cherry pick creates patches from the diffs introduced between the commit and it's immediate predecessor, and applies that patch against the current branch and commits.  A merge will get all the changes since the common ancestor.